# What do you call (and how do you solve) this kind of optimization problem?

Tags: optimization, systems-of-equations

I have a system of equations like:

\begin{cases}
X_1 = a_{11} x_1 + a_{12} x_2 + a_{13} x_3\\\\
X_2 = a_{21} x_1 + a_{22} x_2 + a_{23} x_3\\\\
X_3 = a_{31} x_1 + a_{32} x_2 + a_{33} x_3
\end{cases}

Then I have a "target" such as

$$T = t_1 x_1 + t_2 x_2 + t_3 x_3 $$

I want to choose coefficients $c_1, c_2, c_3$ such that $c_1 X_1 + c_2 X_2 + c_3 X_3$ is as close to $T$ as possible. By "as close to" I mean a least squares distance, so minimizing

$$ ((c_1 a_{11} + c_2 a_{21} + c_3 a_{31}) - t_1)^2 +  ((c_1 a_{12} + c_2 a_{22} + c_3 a_{32}) - t_2)^2 + ((c_1 a_{13} + c_2 a_{23} + c_3 a_{33}) - t_3)^2 $$

My end goal is actually to do this kind of problem in R--if you're able to show me that, amazing, but I'm really just trying to start by figuring out what this kind of problem is called! Right now I don't know what terms to look up or google....

Addendum: in case my notation is unclear, an example with numbers

\begin{cases}
X_1 = 2x_1 + 3x_2 + 4x_3\\\\
X_2 = 3x_1 - 2x_2 + 9x_3\\\\
X_3 = 5x_1 + 4x_2 + 4x_3
\end{cases}

The target is $T = 24x_1 + 12.5x_2 + 36x_3$.

In this case there is a perfect solution $c_1 = 1.5$, $c_2 = 2$, $c3=3$, but in general there won't be a perfect solution and I want to find the closest solution.

Comment: On first looking at this, it doesn't seem like the $x_i$ are playing any real role in your problem. It seems like it could be rephrased using matrices like this. Given a matrix $A = (a_{ij})$ and a target vector $t$ find a vector $x$ so that $Ax = t$ or $(Ax - t) \cdot (Ax-t)$ is minimized. At this point you can just use the hammer of linear algebra to find your answer. If the target vector is in the image of $A$, then there's a perfect solution, if not, you will have to do some more work.

Comment: Thanks! I think you are right. Assuming no perfect solution, any tips on what to look up along the lines of "some more work"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It feels to me that the $x_i$ are more distracting than useful. You are using polynomial notation for what I'd rather consider a vector in this case. So you have $X_1,X_2,X_3,T\in\mathbb R^3$ and want $c_i$ which minimize $\lVert c_1X_1+c_2X_2+c_3X_3−T\rVert^2$.

In this formulation I'd call it a [linear least squares problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares) because you are trying to find the last sum of squares residue, and each coordinate is linear in the parameters you control. Looking at Wikipedia more closely, you also find that this is an [ordinary least squares problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares).

To solve this, you multiply the matrix equation you'd get for the exact case by the transpose of the matrix:

$$A\cdot c\approx t\qquad\rightarrow\qquad A^T\cdot A\cdot c=A^T\cdot t$$

Personally I can't remember which matrix is the original one and which is the transpose, but if you imagine a situation where you are fitting more coordinates in $t$ than you have parameters in $c$ then $A$ needs to have more rows than columns for the equation to even make sense. That will tell you which direction is which.

This should be easy to reproduce in R. The [`crossprod`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/crossprod) function might be of some use.

Come to think of it, if $A$ is square, as in your question, and you don't have a perfect solution, then $A$ must be singular. Which translates back into a linear dependency: one of your polynomials $X_i$ can be expressed as a linear combination of the other two. You can't get a uniquely defined best solution from that. I'd recommend dropping polynomials $X_i$ until you have a basis, i.e. until they are all linearly independent.

Comment: Thanks. I think you are right, the notation and setup should drop the polynomials. But is this then a  linear least squares problem as you say or a quadratic programming problem as the other answer suggests? I expect that usually there will only be a best approximate solution, not an exact solution. p.s. no reason to expect A to always be square. p.p.s. I would like to be able to let the c_i's be zero, that is, to be able to just ignore some rows of A if that helps get a to a better solution.

Comment: @Ben It's both an unconstrained quadratic problem and a linear least squares problem. The latter is more specific and allows for simpler and faster solving, the former class of problems is more generic but I'd say a less useful view if the latter can get the job done. If any of the $c_i$ need to be zero for the optimal solution, the computation will find that. The value of the optimal squared distance is obviously unique, and the corresponding $c$ vector is unique if $A$ has full rank i.e. independent columns. Setting some $c_i=0$ would be ignoring a columns of $A$ not a row.

Comment: Great. thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

This is a *quadratic programming* problem, and the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming) lists a bunch of solvers, many of which are accessible via R.

Comment: Thanks. Is this different than saying this is a linear least squares problem, as suggested by the other answer, or just a different way of talking about the same thing?

Comment: Yes, this is ordinary least squares, which is a special case of linear least squares, which is a special case of quadratic programming.

Comment: Got it. Thanks again!